# Multiply inside of setText

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I am a beginner in Android, so I must ask you for patient :)
Here is a code that I am having a trouble:

```
package com.example.matematika;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PravRacun extends Activity {
EditText editText1, editText2;
TextView output,output2;
Button Izracunaj,Izracunaj2;
BigDecimal rez1, rez2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_prav_racun);

editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Izracunaj=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Izracunaj2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
output2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output2);

Izracunaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

rez1=new BigDecimal(editText1.getText().toString());
rez2=new BigDecimal(editText2.getText().toString());
output.setText(rez1.multiply(rez2).toString());
// here is a problem, how can I change this rez1.multiply(rez2) to something else?

}
});

Izracunaj2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

rez1=new BigDecimal(editText1.getText().toString());
rez2=new BigDecimal(editText2.getText().toString());
output2.setText(rez1.add(rez2).add(rez1).add(rez2).toString());
}
});
}
}
```

So, the line:

//output.setText(rez1.multiply(rez2).toString());

is making me a problem, actually this last line, cause if I try to put that number 2 is multiplying this rez1, it pops up the error. Can I change somehow values?
Basically, I want to take two entered values from EditText field and to do something with them, to put them in some functions.

Thanks a lot.

BR,

Alex

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you create another BigDecimal and put the result in there, then convert that to a string.

```
BigDecimal result = rez1.multiply(rez2);
output.setText(result.toString());
```

It will also give you the opportunity to find out if the problem is in the multiply, or in converting to a string.

Comment: I did it like this, but still I want instead of rez.1multiply(rez2) to make some other function, for example 2*(rez1)+2*(rez2). I dont know how to do that...